# Converting between -180-180 to 0-360

Tags: javascript, math

I have a function that returns an angle from -180 to 180 and I need it to be 0 to 360.  What is the formula to convert the angle?

Here's what I want:

```
   0/360

270      90

    180
```

Here's what I have:

```
        -90

-180/180        0

         90
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, working on an html/javascript game.

Comment: Why should I believe that you have to do it with javascript?You have not shared any code

Comment: Can't you just add 180?

Comment: Lets show us what you did first

Comment: Hi Sandy, welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site has well-defined rules regarding how to form a high quality question that can be answered by the community.  Please review [ask].  Welcome, and happy coding!

Comment: `d => (d + 450) % 360`. Indeed, off topic here, as it is math, not programming. From [tag:math] tag: "Any math questions on this site should be programming related."

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways this can be done while preserving the equivalent angle, with certain assumptions about the values.

If you are sure the values are actually in the range [-180,180), then you can use something like the following:

```
var x = Math.random()*360-180;  // Generate random angle in range [-180, 180)
var y = x < 0 ? x+360 : x;      // Normalize to be in the range [0, 360)
```

If you're doing this a lot, the branch operation may result in poor behavior (though maybe not in Javascript ... you'd need to profile it).  So, it's sometimes better to do this without a branching operation.  You can do this using the modulus (%) operator.

```
var x = Math.random()*360-180;  // Generate random angle in range [-180, 180)
var y = (x + 360) % 360;        // Normalize to be in the range [0, 360)
```

If you cannot guarantee the original value is in the range [-180, 180) you can essentially divide out the number of turns.  This would look like

```
var x = getAngle();   // Some angle, potentially outside [-180, 180)
var y = x - 360 * Math.floor(x/360);  // Normalizes to be in range [0, 360)
```

Some care will need to be taken for large absolute values of x due to the way floating point numbers are represented (which as I understand it is what Javascript uses, even when integer values would work well)

**Edit**:  I just noticed you are also changing where you consider the 0 angle to be (above rather than to the right).  In that case, you need to also add 90 degrees to rotate the 0 into the correct position.  In this case, the first code segment becomes:

```
var x = Math.random()*360-180;  // Generate random angle in range [-180, 180)
var y = x < -90 ? x+450 : x+90;    // Normalize to be in the range [0, 360)
```

The next one becomes as Amadan indicated.

```
var x = Math.random()*360-180;  // Generate random angle in range [-180, 180)
var y = (x + 450) % 360;        // Normalize to be in the range [0, 360)
```

and the last one becomes

```
var x = getAngle();   // Some angle, potentially outside [-180, 180)
var y = (x+90) - 360 * Math.floor((x+90)/360);  // Normalizes to be in range [0, 360)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code as suggested by @Amadan

```js
function convert(deg) {
  return ((deg + 450) % 360);
}

window.console.log(convert(-180));
window.console.log(convert(-90));
window.console.log(convert(0));
window.console.log(convert(90));
window.console.log(convert(180));
```